# How can i make a dictionary from txt file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, read-text

I have get this txt file

```
A:{A:0, B:6, C:4, D:3, E:0, F:0, G:0}

B:{A:6, B:0, C:2, D:0, E:4, F:0, G:0}

C:{A:4, B:2, C:0, D:2, E:0, F:8, G:0}

D:{A:3, B:0, C:2, D:0, E:3, F:0, G:0}

E:{A:0, B:4, C:0, D:3, E:0, F:7, G:6}

F:{A:0, B:0, C:8, D:0, E:7, F:0, G:6}

G:{A:0, B:0, C:0, D:0, E:6, F:6, G:0}
```

---

```
titles = []


with open("graph.txt", "r") as file:

    for line in file:
        column=line.split(":")
        title=column[0]
        titles.append(title)
```

i need to make dictionaries for each title which i got like A,B,C

Comment: What is the expected output? what are the names of the dicts and what is in each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format each line properly and you can use `ast.literal_eval`. I used regex to find each key and replace it with the same key surrounded by quotes.

```
import ast
import re
KEY_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\w+?):')
dics = []
with open('graph.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            dic_str = "{" + KEY_PATTERN.sub(r'"\g<1>":', line) + "}"
            dics.append(ast.literal_eval(dic_str))
print(dics)
```

Can be shorter (though harder to read):

```
import ast
import re
KEY_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\w+?):')

with open('graph.txt') as f:
    dics = [ast.literal_eval("{" + KEY_PATTERN.sub(r'"\g<1>":', line) + "}") for line in f if line.strip()]
print(dics)
```

Output:

```
[{'A': {'A': 0, 'B': 6, 'C': 4, 'D': 3, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'G': 0}}, {'B': {'A': 6, 'B': 0, 'C': 2, 'D': 0, 'E': 4, 'F': 0, 'G': 0}}, {'C': {'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'C': 0, 'D': 2, 'E': 0, 'F': 8, 'G': 0}}, {'D': {'A': 3, 'B': 0, 'C': 2, 'D': 0, 'E':3, 'F': 0, 'G': 0}}, {'E': {'A': 0, 'B': 4, 'C': 0, 'D': 3, 'E': 0, 'F': 7, 'G': 6}}, {'F': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 8, 'D': 0, 'E': 7, 'F': 0, 'G': 6}}, {'G': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 6, 'F': 6, 'G': 0}}]
```

If you want the result to be just one `dict` than change:

```
dics = []
# and
dics.append(ast.literal_eval(dic_str))
```

to

```
dics = {}
# and
dics.update(ast.literal_eval(dic_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following sample:

```
import re
titles = []


with open("graph.txt", "r") as file:

  for line in file:
    if ':' in line:
      title=re.match(r"^(.*?):", line).groups()[0]
      dict_str= re.match("^.*?\{(.*?)\}", line).groups()[0]
      dictionary = {key:value for (key,value) in (item.strip().split(':') for item in dict_str.split(','))}
      titles.append({title: dictionary})
  for item in titles:
    print(item)
```

This will produce output like:

```
{'A': {'A': '0', 'C': '4', 'B': '6', 'E': '0', 'D': '3', 'G': '0', 'F': '0'}}
{'B': {'A': '6', 'C': '2', 'B': '0', 'E': '4', 'D': '0', 'G': '0', 'F': '0'}}
{'C': {'A': '4', 'C': '0', 'B': '2', 'E': '0', 'D': '2', 'G': '0', 'F': '8'}}
{'D': {'A': '3', 'C': '2', 'B': '0', 'E': '3', 'D': '0', 'G': '0', 'F': '0'}}
{'E': {'A': '0', 'C': '0', 'B': '4', 'E': '0', 'D': '3', 'G': '6', 'F': '7'}}
{'F': {'A': '0', 'C': '8', 'B': '0', 'E': '7', 'D': '0', 'G': '6', 'F': '0'}}
{'G': {'A': '0', 'C': '0', 'B': '0', 'E': '6', 'D': '0', 'G': '0', 'F': '6'}}
```